# How can i remove these unwanted columns in my data

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I downloaded the data from uci ml repository and pasted it in excel and i was working on that data but i don't know from where some unwanted columns are coming in my data but in my excel sheet of data no such columns are present

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 506 entries, 0 to 505
Data columns (total 19 columns):
 #   Column       Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------       --------------  -----  
 0   CRIM         506 non-null    float64
 1   ZN           506 non-null    float64
 2   INDUS        506 non-null    float64
 3   CHAS         506 non-null    int64  
 4   NOX          506 non-null    float64
 5   RM           501 non-null    float64
 6   AGE          506 non-null    float64
 7   DIS          506 non-null    float64
 8   RAD          506 non-null    int64  
 9   TAX          506 non-null    int64  
 10  PTRATIO      506 non-null    float64
 11  B            506 non-null    float64
 12  LSTAT        506 non-null    float64
 13  MEDV         506 non-null    float64
 14  Unnamed: 14  0 non-null      float64
 15  Unnamed: 15  0 non-null      float64
 16  Unnamed: 16  0 non-null      float64
 17  Unnamed: 17  0 non-null      float64
 18  Unnamed: 18  1 non-null      object 
dtypes: float64(15), int64(3), object(1)
memory usage: 75.2+ KB
```

The column number from 14 to 18 are unwanted i used drop function but nothing happened. Please help me out with this....

Comment: Why have you paste it in Excel?

Comment: How do you drop the columns?

Answer (score 0):

```
del df[df.Column == 'Unnamed']
```

or:

```
df.drop([14:])
```

In another way:

```
df.drop(df.index[[14:]])
```